# How to parse this json with newtonsoft?

Tags: vb.net

```
{
  "boxes": [
    {
      "hash": "51532859",
      "owner": "9",
      "id": "3868",
      "isDisabled": false
      "innerbox": {
        "color": "aaaa",
        "size": "bbbb"
      }
    },
    {
      "hash": "cccc",
      "owner": "9",
      "id": "3868",
      "isDisabled": false     
      "innerbox": {
        "color": "cccc",
        "size": "dddd"
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "currencies": {
      "USD": {
        "total": "2",
        "value": "123456",
        "currency": "USD",
        "isDisabled": false
      }
    },
    "total": 2
  }
}
```

Above is the JSON (I've cut it down and replaced some info, but its the same format) that I retrieve from a web server. I am trying to use NewtonSoft JSON to Deserialize it but I am getting an error "**because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.**"

Here is my class:

```
Public Class TheBox
    Public Property boxes() As Boxes
    Public Property meta As Meta
    Public Property usd As USD
    Public Property innerbox As InnerBox
End Class

Public Class Meta
    Public Property currencies As Currencies
    Public Property total As Integer
End Class

Public Class Currencies
    Public Property USD As USD
End Class

Public Class USD
    Public Property total As String
    Public Property value As String
    Public Property currency As String
    Public Property isDisabled As Boolean
End Class

Public Class Boxes
    Public Property hash As String
    Public Property owner As String
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property isDisabled As Boolean
End Class

Public Class InnerBox
    Public Property color As String
    Public Property size As String
End Class
```

This is how I am trying to Deserialize it:

```
Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TheBox)(Json)
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: The class Model is not correct. The Root object (your `TheBox`) has only two properties Also `Public Property boxes() As Boxes` should be `Public Property boxes As Box()` or `Public Property boxes As List(Of Box)` -- Use [Json Utils](https://jsonutils.com/) to generate .Net classes in the VB.Net language. -- It won't be correct nonetheless, since it doesn't know how to treat `currencies`: that should be handled as a Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Your current json as posted looks to be "bad" or malformed.

So, this:

```
"isDisabled": false
  "innerbox": {
    "color": "aaaa",
    "size": "bbbb"
  }
```

There is a comma (",") missing after the false.

so, it needs to be:

```
"isDisabled": false,
  "innerbox": {
    "color": "aaaa",
    "size": "bbbb"
  }
```

Same for the one further down.

Once you fix those two issues, then this json will and should parse just fine.

You can have Visual Studio create the classes for you like this:

Create a blank new class, and then ctrl-a and del key to empty out. Then this:

[image]

And now VS spits out this:

```
    Public Class Rootobject
        Public Property boxes() As Box
        Public Property meta As Meta
    End Class

    Public Class Meta
        Public Property currencies As Currencies
        Public Property total As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class Currencies
        Public Property USD As USD
    End Class

    Public Class USD
        Public Property total As String
        Public Property value As String
        Public Property currency As String
        Public Property isDisabled As Boolean
    End Class

    Public Class Box
        Public Property hash As String
        Public Property owner As String
        Public Property id As String
        Public Property isDisabled As Boolean
        Public Property innerbox As Innerbox
    End Class

    Public Class Innerbox
        Public Property color As String
        Public Property size As String
    End Class
```

So, the top most root item here is Root object - you can re-name that if you wish.

I not test above with the above data sample (first fix it), but I'm going for a coffee - if I have time, I will give your data a try with above code later.